# Loose coupling of custom callbacks in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-callback, loose-coupling

I was wondering if there exists a design pattern/framework which allows for the loose coupling of callbacks in jQuery.

Basically, I have a ajax call which retrieves settings that will be required in the callback functions. I have a number of functions that I wish to fire after the ajax call is complete but would like to avoid doing something like:

```
$.getJSON('/webservice/config', function(data) {
    functionA();
    functionB();
}
```

I'd like it to be loosely coupled. Does anyone have an idea on how this is popssible?

Thanks,
  Gearoid.

**SOLUTION**

Here's what I used in the end:

```
function initConfig(callbacks) {

    $.getJSON('/webservices/config', function(data) {       

        $.each(data.config, function(key, value) { 
          config[data.config[key].paramName] = data.config[key].paramValue; 
        });

    }).done(function() {
        //callbacks
        callbacks.forEach(function(callback) {
           if (eval('typeof ' + callback) == 'function') {
            window[callback]();
        });
    });
}
```

My code is then quite loosely coupled as I can pass any number of callback functions to the original function and they will run sequentially, eg:

```
initConfig('setLocationData', 'setUserData');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `jqXHR` object, which is the return value of all AJAX queries, supports a [`done`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/) method which allows you to bind arbitary functions which are executed on the completion of the request;

```
jQuery.getJSON('/foo.json').done(function () {
 // One success handler
}).done(function () {
 // Another success handler
});
```

This is because the AJAX module was rewritten in jQuery 1.5 to use the [Deferred interface](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/), which guarantees the execution of handlers which are bound either before or after the callback fires.

**Edit: Explain my comment**

```
function initConfig() {
    return $.getJSON('/webservices/config', function(data) {       
        $.each(data.config, function(key, value) { 
          config[data.config[key].paramName] = data.config[key].paramValue; 
        });
    });
}

initConfig().done(setLocationData, setUserData);
```

Comment: Thanks this is what I was after. See my question for actual solution I used.

Comment: @Gearóid: Looks good. I'd have considered returning the `jqXHR` from the function and letting the callee add them as necessary (see my edit in my answer!)

Comment: Hmmm, I seem to get an 'initConfig() is undefined' error when I try your approach...

Comment: @Gearóid: You'll probably need to move your `initConfig` declaration **outside** the `jQuery.ready()` block.

Answer (score 1):

The $.ajax function can accept multiple success callbacks. Quote from http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/:

> As of jQuery 1.5, the success setting can accept an array of functions. Each function will be called in turn.

Short example: (see http://jsfiddle.net/JhTDW/)

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/echo/json/',
  success: [
    function(data) {
      document.write('First callback: ' + data + '<br/>');
    },
    function(data) {
      document.write('Second callback: ' + data + '<br/>');
    }
  ]
});
```

Comment: I can't seem to find a code sample where the functions array is passed. Can you create a jsfiddle please?

Comment: In you example, data is the parameter returned by the ajax call correct? The callbacks are independent of data returned, I wish to pass them to the ajax success method, not have the method return them.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how loosely it needs to be coupled, but in the success callback you could always send your `data` object to another function. But I'm not sure how this is going to decouple things. In one case, you're calling `functionA()` and `functionB()` from within the success callback; in the other case you're sending data over to `utilityFunction()` which is running `functionA()` and `functionB()`.

In either case, you could have one or more conditionals in place to run `functionA()` *or* `functionB()` (or whatever other functions). But again, this could be done either in the success callback or in the utility function, so I'm still not sure where the decoupling will happen.

At the core of the question is this: You get `data` back, and presumably you want to act on that data or at least run logic depending on the response. It's about as decoupled as it's going to get, and from there it's just a matter of how you want to structure it.

Comment: You're right in the fact that I wish to act on the data returned. However, I'd like to structure my function with the ajax call in such a way that a number of functions can be passed to it - ie. the function is ignorant of its callbacks.